# Инициализация массива в PHP

Tags: php

Недавно столкнулся с задачей, что нужно массив, состоящий из n элементов инициализировать нулями. Сделал примерно так:

```
for($j=0; $j < $n; $j++)
    $myarray[$j] = 0;
```

Вопрос, можно ли в PHP это сделать проще и удобнее?

Comment: И для любителей регулярок `var_dump(preg_split('~(0)~', str_repeat('0', 10), 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));`. И для нелюбителей `var_dump(str_split(str_repeat('0', 10)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Недавно столкнулся с задачей, что нужно массив, состоящий из n элементов инициализировать нулями. Вопрос, можно ли в PHP это сделать проще и удобнее?

Воспользуйтесь функцией `array_fill`

```
// Аргументы: индекс начала, сколько элементов, значение
$ar = array_fill(0,10,0);

print_r($ar);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
)
```

---

- [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-fill.php) - Создаёт массив и заполняет его значениями.

Comment: В документации в php.net криво написано, ничего он не заполняет, он `создаёт массив, заполненный значениями`

Comment: @vp_arth благодарю поправил.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array_map(function ($b) {
    return 0;
}, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Либо же так: `$array = array_map(create_function('$b', 'return 0;'), $array);`